# DC current amplification

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, dc, mosfet-driver

i'm trying to design a battery charger for 5Ah li-ion battery. Due to cost management problems, i am not able to use advanced 5A charger controller ICs; instead, i am going to use a 1A controller with an amplification stage. Power FET configured as common drain seems a good solution; however, the problem is that, as you know, voltage tolerance of li-ion battery is quite low, about 30mV for my case. Vgs voltage of mosfet leads to voltage loss at the output more than that value. Is there a way to amplify DC current of controller IC by keeping output voltage in specified limits?

thank you.

ps: it is my first question in the site, please let me know if anything is wrong:)

Edit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2RRYa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the output of the controller is directly connected to the input of Nmos. Common drain amplifier is said to be voltage buffer and the DC current amplifier. Assuming 5A will be drawn by the battery during the constant current period and 4.2V will be supplied during constant voltage period, what modifications do I need if the controller supplies 0.5A during CC and 4.2V during CV?

the controller will be something like this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24090.pdf
DC current amplifier should be directly connected between Vout and the positive terminal of the battery pack.

Comment: Welcome,  Negative feedback should cure your voltage offset problem.  It would be best to post a schematic of what you are thinking and then ask for comments/ improvements.

Comment: Does the datasheet (or associated application notes) for the controller you're using show examples for boosting the output current? They often do.

Comment: thank you all for your kind responses. i will re-edit the post as recommend. @DaveTweed yes, they often do to arrange how much output current will be drawn within the limit of controller. since the battery requires more current than that limit of the controller that will be used, another DC current boosting stage is required, i think.

Comment: @mkeith i have just take look at the controller you have sent. What I understand from the original datasheet is that it is possible arrange the output current by changing the value of Rsense resistor. Does it make sense using 11mO/1.1W resistance to get 10A current?